# R: corrplot cl.lim range smaller than the data range

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have a matrix M where values in `M[,1]` are much bigger than in the other columns. I would like to use corrplot with `method="number"` for it, but with:

```
cl.lim=c(min(M[,2:ncol(M)]),max(M[,2:ncol(M)]))
```

Even if I use `is.corr=FALSE`, I'm getting:

```
Error in corrplot(...,  :   color limits should cover matrix
```

Can I somehow force that values outside cl.lim range will have colors of range boundary?

**Example:**

```
M<-cbind(rnorm(10)*10,rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
corrplot(M,tl.pos="lt",is.corr =FALSE,method="number",cl.pos="n",mar=c(0,0,1,0))
```

I'm geting:

[corrplot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6otx.png)

2nd and 3rd column are not visible, because the values are too small.

I tried:

```
corrplot(M,tl.pos="lt",is.corr = FALSE,method="number",cl.pos="n",mar=c(0,0,1,0),cl.lim=c(min(M[,2:3]),max(M[,2:3])))
```

and it caused the error:

```
Error in corrplot(M, tl.pos = "lt", is.corr = FALSE, method = "number",  
: color limits should cover matrix
```

Comment: Please add the complete code (including the corrplot code) and provide some sample data that reproduces the problem

Comment: I've provided simple example that describes my problem.

Comment: Doesn't  the first argument of corrplot need to be a correlation matrix?

Comment: Technically no, it works with all matrices. When you put `is.corr =FALSE` you can visualize non-correlation matrix.

Comment: Well that's the problem.  Looking at the values in your image it is clearly not getting converted to a correlation. Why don't you just try doing that first and see if that helps.   You could standardize or just subset your matrix so as not to include the outlier column.

Comment: That is the case. I don't want to change the data. This auto scale coloring works fine with data with the same range, but I'm looking for a solution when data has different ranges.

Comment: The scaling refers to the values across the whole matrix. It is working as expected.  Either you need to change the values or separate them out or use a different technique that highlights within columns rather than over the whole matrix.

Comment: Ok, so I will look for some alternative solution if it's impossible in corrplot. Thanks

Comment: Note, for corrplot versions 0.9.0 and onward cl.lim was changed to col.lim